# Javascript 'too much recursion' on a simple factorial function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I went over more than a few 'too much recursion' questions and answers here but each of them solves a specific issue, yet I couldn't deduce a proper answer from them to answer this code error, how to solve it and why I'm getting that error:

```
<body>
<input type="number" id="num">
<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="factor()"><br>
<div id="yourResult"></div>
<script>
    inputValue = document.getElementById('num').val;
    function factor(n){
        if(n==0){
            return 1;
        }
        if(n==1){
            return 1;
        }
        return n * factor(n-1);
    }
    function result() {
        $('yourResult').append('<p>your factorial of ' + inputValue + ' equals to: ' + factor()+'</p>');
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to pass input to the function the first time you're calling it, otherwise it'll do infinite recursion.

Comment: pass parameter in function calling or check with input value not n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter value.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="number" id="num">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Get Factorial" onclick="result()"><br>
<div id="yourResult"></div>
<script>

    function factor(n){
        if(n==0){
            return 1;
        }
        if(n==1){
            return 1;
        }
        return n * factor(n-1);
    }
    function result() {
        inputValue = document.getElementById('num').value;
        $('#yourResult').append('<p>your factorial of ' + inputValue + ' equals to: ' + factor(inputValue)+'</p>');
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: vote those comment also which looks you useful it help others

Comment: Hi Sinsuren, thanks for your answer, but: 1.) your code returns the same error ('too many recursions') 2.) I know the iterative approach but I need it to work in a recursive approach, please refer again to my question. Check your answer, it doesn't work mate.

Comment: Yes it does, it works great now and you kept the uniformity of the code and really helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey @clusterBuddy make it correct `document.getElementById('num').val`
 to `document.getElementById('num').value` and try below code it will
 gives you the factorial result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function factor(){
    var n=document.getElementById("num").value;


      var factorial = function(n) {
        if(n == 0) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }

      }
      document.getElementById("yourResult").innerHTML ="your factorial is"+factorial(n);

  }
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="factor()"><br>
<span id="yourResult"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: You changed a few things but your code works like gold. Thank you Mr. Vishal.

Answer (score 0):

This function can be easier:

```js
function factor(n) {return !!+n && (n <= 1 ? n : n * factor(--n))}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).